# Cross Site Scripting - Is This Ok?

Tags: cross-domain

I have a solution that I believe makes use of cross site scripting.  Since I control the the code in the target of the cross site scripting, I am thinking this might be an acceptable solution.

**Does this solution expose my client or my client's problem to a cross site scripting risk that needs to be, or should be avoided?**

## Details

A client needs to provide one of its partners with " HTML to put OUR page on their site."  In this case, our page is at this link:
Source Link:  http://booknook.biz/bk_promos/WBC_Exclusive

The partner is operating another domain, http://hollylisle.com/, where they want to run that page.

Copying the page source from the source link above into a file save as html appears to produce a file that runs on any webserver, such as this test at this link:
http://launchpad-001.com/formForHollyLisle/bn_landingPage.html

Comment: Where is the cross site scripting? All i'm seeing is an html page that references external assets, which isn't cross-site scripting. The only thing harmful about it would be the external site could potentially change/remove the assets causing the copied page to no longer work. An iframe would likely be more appropriate.

Comment: @DanAllen There's actually a pretty good wikipedia article that you can use as a starting point to learn more about XSS at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting.  You can also read more about XSS if you take a look at articles on content security policies, such as http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the solution does not expose my client to cross site scripting risk.  The primary reason is the solution does not have any cross site scripting in it.  As explained by Kevin B, the web page has references to external assets.  I mistook that for cross site scripting.  Linking to external assets is not a security risk, since I am controlling the external assets.